# java static initializer called twice

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader, static-initializer

```
static boolean isClassLoaded(String fullname) {
    try {
        Class.forName(fullname, false, Loader.instance().getModClassLoader());
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

does this method has potential to trigger fullname's static initializer ?
i have problem with static initializer called twice.
when i try to check if class loaded using isClassLoaded and try to use that class, i get error because of constructor called twice.
anyone know what is problem with Class.forName(fullname, false, Loader.instance().getModClassLoader()); ?

Comment: It’s not clear where `Loader.instance().getModClassLoader()` comes from and what it does. Further, you are talking about a “constructor called twice” but not what constructor of which class and how this relates to the “static intitializer” of your question’s title.

Comment: I could replace them with ThisClass.class.getClassLoader();

Comment: In that case, no initializer should get invoked and whatever exception in whatever constructor occurs has nothing to do with static initializers.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is a flag called "initialize".

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-):

> The class is initialized only if the initialize parameter is true and
>   if it has not been initialized earlier.

So, if `initialize` is set to `false`, it will not execute your static initializers.

**Self-contained example**

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("test.Main$Foo", false, Main.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println("blah");
        Class.forName("test.Main$Foo", true, Main.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    static class Foo {
        static {
            System.out.println("Foo static initializer");
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
blah
Foo static initializer
```

Note it would always print `Foo static initializer` only once, but here, it prints `blah` first, i.e. the first `Class.forName` invocation did not execute the static initializer.